# Select specific element type with specific ID in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to find any `canvas` elements with the id `whatever` using jQuery. 
I thought I could do `$('canvas #whatever')` but that doesn't return anything when I have a canvas with that id on the page.

Comment: You can only have one element with the id 'whatever' per page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,   `$('canvas#whatever')`

This should work.

Answer (score 6):

Your selector will return an element that is a canvas's child. Doing `$('#whatever')` should already return what you expect, since IDs should be unique in a page.

Anyway, if you really want to be more specific, the correct way to retrieve a canvas with this ID is to remove your space there: `$('canvas#whatever')`

Answer (score 1):

if you want multiple elements with the same identifier use classes and then reference it $("canvas .yourclass"). I'm not sure if thats what's causing your issue but if its not a unique ID it's not right.

Answer (score 1):

Try class = whatever instead, seems to work better. Canvases with the same Id behave strangely.

```js
$('.whatever').css('background-color','green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="whatever" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
<canvas class="whatever" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
<canvas class="whatever" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The empty space you leave after the element type implies that the following selector concerns children of that element. 
You need to keep the whole selector tight together, no spaces.

```
$('canvas#whatever')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('canvas#whatever')
```

or

```
$('canvas[id=whatever]')
```